# Swift 5 Scanner class is slow

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm using Swift [`Scanner`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/scanner) to parse strings and numeric values from text files.

Since Catalina (10.15) it is possible to use `scanDouble()`, `scanInt()`, `scanUpToCharacters(from:)` and `scanUpTo(string:)` methods. All of them return Optionals.

Before Catalina those functions worked directly by reference and returned boolean values indicating if the operation was successful. Function signature was like: `scanDouble(&result)`. At that time I implemented the above four functions myself like this:

```
fileprivate extension Scanner {
    func scanUpToCharacters(from set: CharacterSet) -> String? {
        var result: NSString?
        return scanUpToCharacters(from: set, into: &result) ? (result as String?) : nil
    }

    func scanUpTo(_ string: String) -> String? {
        var result: NSString?
        return self.scanUpTo(string, into: &result) ? (result as String?) : nil
    }

    func scanDouble() -> Double? {
        var double = 0.0
        return scanDouble(&double) ? double : nil
    }

    func scanInt() -> Int? {
        var int = 0
        return scanInt(&int) ? int : nil
    }
}
```

This worked perfectly though, but now that I'm on Catalina and since `Scanner` methods using pointers are now deprecated I removed my private extension to use standard library implementation.

The problem is when I profiled my application the time requirement on file parsing exploded. I investigated the issue and found that standard library implementation is near 8 times slower than my previous implementation.

Is it a known bug or I'm using the standard library in the wrong way?

Note that since function signature is the same between standard library and my implementation I just comment my extension to profile the code, hence nothing changes excepted the four function calls.

Comment: The main problem is the use of the "Index" structure of "String" class. Swift is designed to be "unicode friendly" and uses that structure to handle the position of a character in the string.

In addition to the above, there is the penalty for ARC, which in Swift, seems to be more expensive than in Obj-C.

I write my own "Scanner" implementation, since iterating through an array of 330k+ strings would take an amount of time 1:41 mins. After a lot of work in implementation and optimization, I managed to lower the time to just 0:15 mins. The same task in Obj-C takes 0:02 mins.

Comment: Okay, so Scanner is a too broad and general parser, I only parse ascii characters so a far more efficient implementation is possible.

Comment: Yes it is posible, but you need work with pointers in Swift. ( https://medium.com/@prafullkumar77/pointers-in-swift-f8d651d0e724 ), and a good reading ( https://www.fast.ai/2019/01/10/swift-numerics/ )